# Linear algebra and vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

If each of two vectors a and b are linearly dependent on two other vectors x and y, would a and b also be linearly dependent always?

Comment: Here the size of each vectors is 2*1

Comment: What do you think ?

Comment: I think a b can be linearly dependent or independent.

Comment: But how to show this?

Comment: Or prove or disprove this?

Answer (score 1):

No, and you can show that with one example

In general, linear dependence means that $$\begin{aligned}\boldsymbol{a} & =\alpha_{x}\boldsymbol{x}+\alpha_{y}\boldsymbol{y}\\
\boldsymbol{b} & =\beta_{x}\boldsymbol{x}+\beta_{y}\boldsymbol{y}
\end{aligned}$$

for some scalar values $\alpha_x$, $\alpha_y$ and $\beta_x$, $\beta_y$. By definition, $\boldsymbol{x}$ and $\boldsymbol{y}$ must be linearly independent for the above to work.

$$\begin{aligned}\boldsymbol{a} & =1\boldsymbol{x}+0\boldsymbol{y}\\
\boldsymbol{b} & =0\boldsymbol{x}+1\boldsymbol{y}
\end{aligned}$$

then the vectors $\boldsymbol{a}$ and $\boldsymbol{b}$ are linearly independent.

To check for *linear dependency*, check if the following determinant is zero

$$ {\rm det}(\boldsymbol{a},\,\boldsymbol{b}) = \begin{vmatrix} \alpha_x & \alpha_y \\ \beta_x & \beta_y \end{vmatrix} \overset{?}{=}  0 $$

and in the example above $\begin{vmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{vmatrix} \neq 0$ which means that the two vectors $\boldsymbol{a}$ and $\boldsymbol{b}$ are linearly *indepedent*.